# How to explain privacy to a family member

Tags: privacy

A family member of mine does some courses for fun where people come to her home and partake in these courses. However for this she has a publicly available website on which she has her Home Address available for anyone to see.

I tried explaining to her why that is probably not such a good idea, and she should send out emails to people that actually sign up and pay etc. with the actual address. But she doesn't see any reason for hiding her address.

How can I explain this to her in a way she will understand. (She is not very tech savvy)

Comment: Why do *you* think she needs to hide her address. Addresses are very public info. And why does she need to be tech savvy?

Comment: This has nothing to do with tech savvy-ism, and it is completely fine to decide that you don't mind having your address available online. If anything, it's the letting strangers into her house that I would oppose...

Comment: I would be very nervous if my full name + address + phone number was available for anyone to see online.